# Layout Changes When I Run App On My Phone

Tags: android, android-layout, button, textview, android-edittext

On my graphical layout in Eclipse, the EditView, TextView, and button are where I want them to be. But when I run them on my phone, they are moved to a different location. Can someone help me keep them where I want them to be?

Here's my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundhdpi" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bill"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:text="Enter Your Bill"
            android:textSize="18dip" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculateTip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bill"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Calculate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tipOwed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bill"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="123dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:text="Time to Tip!"
            android:textColor="#2c6f37"
            android:textSize="35dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to post your layout code. Also, if you are designing using a different device theme in the layout editor, it will look different on your phone if your phone is a different screen size / density.

Comment: Perhaps screenshots of what you want it to look like and what it actually looks like.

Comment: @user1657178 Please add the screenshots as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I may ask, what type/unit of phone do you try to run your code? The layout of the program on a user's view of point is, at times, dependent to the screen of the phone they are using.

Example:

You run the app with an Galaxy S2 emulator, and you try to run it in a Galaxy Y. With the  difference of the screen resolution of the two, you could notice the difference between the space that the layout could occupy.

Also, are you placing the images that are being used in your layout in a single drawable folder? Like for example, drawable-hdpi? 
Placing images that will be later on used by your layout in different drawable folders could affect directly the size or resolution of the image.

Comment: Just an FYI this should probably be a comment, not an answer, as you haven't really given a solution to anything :)